# Postgres: SELECT column name based on Boolean value

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table containing Boolean values for travel modes, which looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM survey;
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | bike  |  car  |  bus  | metro |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 49 | false | false | true  | false |
| 51 | false | true  | false | false |
| 52 | false | false | false | true  |
| 53 | false | true  | false | false |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Then I want select only the modes for which the value is `true`, so that the end result is:

```
+----+-------+
| id | mode  |
+----+-------+
| 49 | bus   |
| 51 | car   |
| 52 | metro |
| 53 | car   |
+----+-------+
```

How I achieve this please?

Comment: What if more than one column has a true value for a given row?

Comment: I can confirm no two columns have `true` values for same record as the survey allows user to select one travel mode only.

Comment: Looks like a very bad data model then. Make this two tables: one for the travel modes, one for the surveys. The survey table would contain a column referencing the associated travel mode row (e.g. id_travelmode). The query you are looking for would become a mere join of the two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select
    id,
    case
        when bike  = true then 'bike'
        when car   = true then 'car'
        when bus   = true then 'bus'
        when metro = true then 'metro'
    end mode
from survey
```

This supposes that for each row, only one column is true. If not, only the value of the first matching column will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below way -

```
select id, mode from
(
select id, 'bike' as mode,bike as val from tablename
union all
select id, 'car',car from tablename
union all
select id, 'bus',bus from tablename
union all
select id, 'metro',metrofrom tablename
)A where val=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some JSONB magic to avoid listing all columns:

```
select id, 
       (select k
        from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(s) - 'id') as x(k,v)
        where x.v = 'true') as mode
from survey s
order by id;
```

`to_jsonb(s) - 'id'` converts the whole row into a JSON value where the column name is the key and removes the `id` key. `jsonb_each_text()` then returns all values as text and picks the key where the value is `true`

Comment: Ah, yeah. But I think this would be slow for very large records.

Comment: @arilwan: I don't, but you have to check for yourself. But this is the price you have to pay for a de-normalized data model