# Select column names in geopandas df based on boolean values

Tags: pandas

I have a geopandas dataframe thus

```
mmsi    lat    lng    Paul    Art    Bob
123     51     65     True    False  False
234     78     91     False   True   False
345     45     13     False   False  True
456     61     79     False   False  False
```

I am trying to extract the column name where column value is True, so the expected output would be

```
mmsi   name
123    Paul
234    Art
345    Bob
```

Any suggestions as to how I can achieve this? The example here ([Postgres: SELECT column name based on Boolean value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58591079/postgres-select-column-name-based-on-boolean-value)) is a similar problem, but the solution does not work for me.

There will only ever be one True value per row. Some rows may be all False. However, the column names are dynamic (the data is from an API call) and may change, so the solution should ideally to be generic and scalable. The json solution by a_horse_with_no_name (above link) looks close to what I'm looking for, but I get a syntax error when trying to implement it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
df_names = df[df.columns.difference(['mmsi','lat','lng'])]
m = df_names.any(axis = 1)
new_df = (df.loc[m,['mmsi']]
            .join(df_names.dot(df_names.columns)
                          .rename('name')))
print(new_df)
   mmsi  name
0   123  Paul
1   234   Art
2   345   Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df['Paul'] | df['Art'] | df['Bob']].drop(['lat','lng'],1).set_index('mmsi')\
      .replace(True, pd.Series(df.columns,df.columns))\
      .apply(lambda x: ''.join([i for i in list(x) if i != False]),1).reset_index(name='name)

   mmsi  name
0   123  Paul
1   234   Art
2   345   Bob
```